# Unable to cast the type 'Anonymous type' to type 'Transcriber.Models.Jobs'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types

Tags: c#, linq

When I am calling `fetchGroups` method I got an error in

```
var result = gp.Cast<Jobs>().ToList();
```

I am very new to linq. Any suggestion please.

Model:

```
public List<Jobs> fetchGroups(decimal Trans_ID, decimal Job_Id)
{
    var gp = (from Trans_Mast in r2ge.Transcription_Tracker
                      where Trans_Mast.Transcription_Id == Trans_ID && 
                            Trans_Mast.Entity_Id == Job_Id
                      select
                          new
                          {
                              Trans_Mast.Group_Name
                          }).Distinct();
    var result = gp.Cast<Jobs>().ToList();
    return result;
}

public class Job
{
    List<Room> room = new List<Room>();
    public int totalImage { get; set; }
    public int totalAudio { get; set; }
    public int Transcribe_Rooms { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to return an `anonymous` type but the return type of your method is `List<Jobs>`. So instead of `select new { }` in `gp` you need `select new Jobs { }`.

Comment: @RahulSingh thnx for ur reply I have solved it by directly converting into enumerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of problem is

```
    List<string> gp = (from Trans_Mast in r2ge.Transcription_Tracker
                       where Trans_Mast.Transcription_Id == Trans_ID && Trans_Mast.Entity_Id == Job_Id && Trans_Mast.Group_Name != null
                       select new
                       {
                           Trans_Mast.Group_Name
                       }).AsEnumerable().Select(dr => dr.Group_Name).Distinct().ToList();
```